# Copy Entry widget text and paste into another Entry widget in the same window

Tags: python, tkinter

How do I copy Entry widget text and paste into another Entry widget in the same window.

i.e. Let's imagine you are completing a joint credit application but you and the co-applicant have the same mailing address. Instead of re-typing the same address over again, there should be a checkbutton on the application that when it's checked it will auto-populate the co-applicant's mailing address with the main applicant's address. How do I get this done in tkinter? (**I'm a tkinter and python rookie**) 
thanks in advance DP​

Comment: What research have you done prior to asking this question? The answers you seek are all in readily available documentation and tutorials.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and word it better. I'd start by improving the title, right now it's pretty unclear what the question is about.

Comment: @BryanOakley  please share where this info...I could not find out how to accomplish this task

Comment: @Nae is that better?

Comment: @DP9007036 See [tkinter tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tkinter/info) for more info on resources.

Comment: There can be a number of ways creating a GUI that fits your description. Please narrow down your description better. Perhaps provide a [mcve] and tell exactly how you want to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

There can probably a couple more ways of achieving the behavior you want. I think using the `textvariable` option and `Variable Classes` fits well here. Together, they let a widget's text to be the same as another at all times. With the `Checkbutton` the user decides whether or not to do that:

```
try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk


def on_selection(copy_widget, paste_widget, condition_widget):
    if condition_widget.var.get():
        paste_widget['textvariable'] = copy_widget['textvariable']
    else:
        paste_widget['textvariable'] = ''


def create_entry_widgets(master):
    entries = list()
    for i in range(2):
        entries.append(tk.Entry(master))
        entries[-1].pack()
    entries[0].var = tk.StringVar()
    entries[0]['textvariable'] = entries[0].var
    return entries


def create_checkbutton(master, entries):
    checkbutton = tk.Checkbutton(master, text="Copy?")
    checkbutton.var = tk.BooleanVar(value=False)
    checkbutton.config(variable=checkbutton.var, onvalue=True, offvalue=False)
    checkbutton['command'] = lambda cw=entries[0], pw=entries[1], \
                                    cdw=checkbutton: on_selection(cw, pw, cdw)
    checkbutton.pack()
    return checkbutton


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    entries = create_entry_widgets(root)
    checkbutton = create_checkbutton(root, entries)   
    tk.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```